# Mysql distinct or not

Tags: mysql

I have a `mytable` like the following:

```
id  child
1       
2   1
3   1
4   
5   
6   5
7    
8
```

etc.
I want to select all children and all parents only.

for this example it shoul be:

```
id child
1 
2  1
3  1
5 
6  5
```

I created select like this:

> SELECT * FROM mytable where (`child` <> '') or `id` IN (SELECT
>   distinct(`child`) FROM mytable where `child` <> '');

but perhaps it could be done  more elegant way, especially having speed in mind.

Comment: Your expected output is very unclear. Can you please explain it?

Comment: so 4/7/8 should be exluded because they're not a parent or child of any other record?

Comment: @Marc B - yes exactly

Comment: OP, I'm not sure what your question is. Your query works just fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mytable.* 
FROM mytable
JOIN mytable AS t2
WHERE mytable.id = t2.child
AND t2.child <> ''
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE child <> ''
GROUP BY id, child
```

Provided you have an index on id and another on child this will use an index for both sides.  The GROUP BY will give a hit for performance but is necessary to prevent duplicate records from the first part of the UNION.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is start by getting a list of children like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT child
FROM myTable
WHERE child IS NOT NULL;
```

This will give you 1 and 5. Then all you need to do is select rows where the id is in the above subquery, OR where the child is in the above subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE id IN(
  SELECT DISTINCT child
  FROM myTable
  WHERE child IS NOT NULL)
OR child IN(
  SELECT DISTINCT child
  FROM myTable
  WHERE child IS NOT NULL)
AND child IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3ae51/4) example.